# Using Registration Confirmation Link after 24 hours to create an account then Order is not showing up in Order History

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.2-p2

I am using Magento version 2.4.2-p2

Here's the scenario:

1. If I use the link within the day, I am able to create an account and see the order in Order History.
2. If I use the link after 24 hours, I'm still able to create an account but the order is not available in Order History.

Where can I find the setting to adjust the Registration Confirmation Link that you receive upon checkout?

Also, why is it that if I use the link within the day I am able to see the Order History regardless of the order state. But once 24 hours passed then use the link at that time, I cannot see the order in Order History.

Answer (score 0):

[image: customer_entity in db]

You need a custom module, where confirmation expired.
The best to do this is

- new date column in customer_entity confirmation_exp
- check if confirmation_exp is valid
- new generation of confirmation column and save, also update confirmation_exp